# Remove directory at an arbitrary depth in another directory

Tags: bash, find

I use `find` with basic arguments like `-name`, but reading the manual didn't help me achieve finding nested folders of arbitrary depth.

Specifically I want to find (and delete) all the folders `inputs` which are within folders named `cromwell-executions`. There are multiple enclosing folders with the same name (but not nested if that is relevant) and each can contain many instances of `inputs` folders at different depths.

How can I achieve that with `find`?

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the **-path** primary. Select each directory whose path matches `*/cromwell-executions/*`, and queue it for deletion if it is named `inputs`. The predicate **-prune** makes sure `find` does not descend into a directory that was marked for removal in the previous step.

```
find . -type d -path '*/cromwell-executions/*' -name 'inputs' -exec echo rm -r {} + -prune
```

Drop `echo` if the output looks good.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass all of the `cromwell-executions` directories as arguments and tell `find` to search within each.

```
find **/cromwell-executions -name inputs -exec echo rm -r {} + -prune
```

Drop `echo` if the output looks good.

<sub>(This is a shorter but less general alternative to [oguz ismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65394517/68587).)</sub>

Comment: This also works great! Small advantage to oguz solution because it doesn't reply on shell wildcards!